# Error: "SRJWT02002: Failed to read the public key content from 'mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location'" with the file inside a Jar

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus

**I have a publickey.pem file located inside the resource folder of a Jar library**. I have a dependency with that library in my project and I use that file indicating it in the property

`mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=publickey.pem`

In **Quarkus version 2.13 it worked fine** and I could find the file, but **after upgrading to version 2.16 it stopped working** and I got this error:

`SRJWT02002: Failed to read the public key content from 'mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location'`

I haven't changed anything else in the code, and if I switch back to version 2.13 it works again.

Do you know if anything has changed between these versions and I need to add some new property or something?

I have tried to copy the publickey.pem file to the resource folder of the project and it works in Quarkus 2.16. But if it is in the resource folder of a jar library it does not find it. In Quarkus 2.13 it did find it.

Comment: Hey Roberto, did you manage to figure it out?